# Does iCloud backup only backup non-deleted pictures?

Tags: icloud, backup, graphics

I have deleted some photos on my iPad (both from camera roll and photo stream) and I never want them to be found. I heard that you can use "iCloud backup" to restore your stuff in case your iPad crashes or whatever. If at some point I were to backup my iPad, would those    pictures still be found even though I have deleted them? If so, how can they be gotten  rid of forever? I know this probably sounds very strange, but it would be nice to know just in case of emergency.

Answer (score -1):

The pictures won't return as long as you did a backup after you deleted them from your device.